# Discrepancy in numbers between Bellum Judaicum and Antiquitate

Tags: josephus

I'm trying to resolve the differences between Josephus' Bellum Judaicum [2.224-27 (2.12.1)] and his Antiquitates [20.105-12 (20.5.3)] with respect to the number of Jews massacred in the temple under Claudius. BJ has 30,000 while Antiquitates has 20,000. I was able to find the 20K at Gutenberg.org: (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2848/2848-h/2848-h.htm#link20noteref-10).
I'm unable to confirm the 30K number anywhere. I'm wondering if the reference I'm using is incorrect in the 30K stat. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for History Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

[Bellum Judaicum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0148:book=2:whiston+chapter=12:whiston+section=1) has ten thousand, and [Antiquitates Judaicae](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0146:book=20:whiston+chapter=5:whiston+section=3) has twenty thousand. The thirty thousand figure seems to be their sum, assuming the two to have been distinct battles.